# Co(ntra)variance in an parameter of a delegate

Tags: c#, parameters, delegates, covariance

I want to create a delegate pointing to a static function...the static function has a second parameter of type Flight, the Flight class implements ITravelObject interface and the second delegate parameter requires this interface.

The following code doesn't work. Why is that? Is there any other possible implementation?

```
namespace CovarianceContravarianceTest
{

    public class Data {}

    public interface ITravelObject
    {
        int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class BaseObject {}

    public class Flight : BaseObject, ITravelObject
    {
        int ITravelObject.ID {get;set;}
    }

    public static class LetService
    {
        public static void DoSomething(Data da, Flight let) {}
    }

    public delegate void TravelServiceMethodDelegate(Data dataAccess,ITravelObject     travelObject);

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TravelServiceMethodDelegate test = new TravelServiceMethodDelegate(LetService.DoSomething);
        }
    }
```

}

This results in error

No overload for 'DoSomething' matches delegate 'CovarianceContravarianceTest.TravelServiceMethodDelegate'

**thanks everyone for answers, I've already figured out this isn't even a covariance/contravariance issue**

Comment: Are you *sure* that is the code you're having problems with? There is no difference between the delegate signature here and the method group you're trying to apply it to. **This should compile**!

Comment: @Motig: What version of .NET are you compiling in?  Some earlier versions had issues with covariance that later ones don't.  This succeeds for me in .NET 4.0

Comment: That code is fine. Try again.

Comment: This code [works for me](http://ideone.com/TJZt6).  So does [this variation](http://ideone.com/TJZt6) which uses variance.

Comment: error repaired...though i suspect i already know why its not working

Comment: I just pasted that code into Visual Studio and ran it -- it compiled and no exception was generated.  I even tried invoking delegate "test" and that was fine too.

Comment: please copy and paste it again, it won't work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to plug this method

```
public static void DoSomething(Data da, Flight let) {}
```

into this delegate

```
var test = new TravelServiceMethodDelegate(LetService.DoSomething);
```

This cannot work. Why? Consider the following code:

```
class CarRide : ITravelObject { }

void GoForACarRide(TravelServiceMethodDelegate travelService) {
    travelService.Invoke(someData, new CarRide());
}
```

This compiles, because `CarRide` implements `ITravelObject`.

However, if I call `GoForACarRide(test)`, it will break, since `test` points to `DoSomething`, which expects a `Flight`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work, because it's not safe. You are trying to create a delegate that claims that it accepts any `ITravelObject`, but it would actually work only for `Flight`. This is not safe and so it's not allowed.

It would work the other way round, though. This code compiles:

```
public delegate void TravelServiceMethodDelegate(Data dataAccess, Flight travelObject);

…

var test = new TravelServiceMethodDelegate(LetService.DoSomething);
```

Answer (score 1):

If that were possible, you could do this:

```
namespace CovarianceContravarianceTest
{
    public interface ITravelObject { }

    public class Flight :  ITravelObject
    {
        public void Fly() { }
    }

    public class Cruise :  ITravelObject
    {
        public void Sail() { }
    }

    public static class LetService
    {
        public static void GoFlying(Flight flight) 
        {
            flight.Fly();
        }

        public static void GoSailing(Cruise cruise)
        {
            cruise.Sail();
        }  
    }

    public delegate void TravelServiceMethodDelegate(ITravelObject travelObject);

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new TravelServiceMethodDelegate(LetService.GoFlying);

            test(new Cruise());
        }
    }
}
```

Passing a `cruise` to `GoFlying()` obviously would't work. A `Cruise` isn't a `Flight`.